# BlueSky Statistics - String to date [time] issues

Tags: r, rgui

Trying to convert time as a string to a time variable.
Use Date/Dates/Convert String to Date...... for format I use %H:%M:%S....
Here is the syntax from the GUI

### [Convert String Variables to Date]

BSkystrptime (varNames = c('Time'),dateFormat = "%H:%M:%S",prefixOrSuffix = "prefix",prefixOrSuffixValue = "Con_",data = "Dataset2") 
BSkyLoadRefreshDataframe(dframe=Dataset2,load.dataframe=TRUE)
A screen shot of result is attached....
Compare variables Time [string] to Con_Time [date/time]
The hours are 2 hours out [wrong!] - the Minutes and Seconds are correct.
What am I doing wrong here?
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlu58.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running into a known issue with a prior release of  BlueSky Statistics. This issue is fixed with the current stable release available on the download page.

The reason for this was although the time is converted correctly into the local time zone, BlueSky Statistics was reading the time zone in the local time zone and converting it to UTC.

You are probably +2 hours ahead of UTC, so you are seeing the time move 2 hrs back. Give us a couple of days to post a patch.

You can also confirm this by writing and executing the following syntax in the syntax window

Dataset2$Con_Time

Comment: Thank you for the response. Downloaded latest version & issue is solved.